# Azure Cognitive Services Translator: any criteria to determine whether translation gave reliable results or not?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

We'd like to show some indication on the UI to draw user's attention if translation was unsuccessful. By 'unsuccessful' I mean not internal server errors or similar but the case when the results are not that good or reliable. It can be caused by a bad input text for instance.

The thing is that the API always returns something even if we send dummy data like 'ksalnfdljknrwwonfjlksnfk  nasnfoaewrnnfsjklnfs 294#ffklsdfl' into it. In those cases the API  normally returns a copy of the input. And we would like to get some score (e.g. a number from 0 to 1) or anything like that.

I was thinking about checking if output == input, but, unfortunately, sometimes word's translations are identical in different languages, e.g 'hamster' in English and German.
Then I was thinking about additional preliminary input language detection to indicate if the input data are nonsense. The good thing about Detection API is that it returns a score. But it's not clear what threshold to use for the Score value.

So, hypothetically, **IF input's score is < 0.3 (for instance) AND input == output THEN show an error message.**

What do you think about such an approach? What is your solution for this problem? What constants could I use for thresholds? Perhaps there are other criterias or Azure API has other parameters which we are not aware about but could be helpful.

Here is a piece of distilled code in C# to send a request to API:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Relesys.Core.Translation
{
    public class TranslationService
    {
    private static readonly string _endpoint = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
    private static readonly string _subscriptionKey = "******************************";

    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TranslationService()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    }

    public async Task<string> SendTranslateRequestAsync(string originalText)
    {
        List<string> routeAttributes = new List<string>
        {
            "api-version=3.0", // always set api version
            "textType=html", // The translate service should expect text from an html text input (as it might contain html)
            "to=de",
            "from=en"
        };

        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            // Body content to send
            object[] body = new object[] { new { Text = originalText } };
            string requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri($"{_endpoint}/translate?{string.Join("&", routeAttributes)}");
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _subscriptionKey);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return jsonResult;
            }

            string failedResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            throw new Exception(failedResult);
        }
    }
}
}
```